# Connect to remote windows machine using using Java when cygwin is not installed in the remote machine

Tags: java, cygwin, remote-access, jsch, psexec

I tried to connect to a remote windows machine using JSCH and the connection was successful.

```
String ipAddress = "54.678.90.09";
String username = "Admin";
String password = "asd-!@#";
if (platform.equalsIgnoreCase("windows")) {
  session = jsch.getSession(username, ipAddress, 22);
   session.setPassword(password);
}
```

I tried the same by stopping the cygwin service, but the connection was not successful.

I would like to connect to a remote windows machine which does not have cygwin installed and execute commands in command prompt using java.

I had a chance to look into Psexec tool, but the security is taking a hit.

Can someone suggest some other ideas to connect to a remote windows machine using Java and execute commands?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to establish a SSH session to that remote system.

That of course requires that an **ssh service** is running there. It seems that cygwin provided that.

If that is not the case, you simply has to install some other product that provides this service, see [here](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/guide_windows_openssh_server) for example.

Comment: Any comments by the downvoter? What exactly is wrong with the observation that you need a SSH service running and listening on port 22 in order to connect a SSH session to that port?!

Comment: I know that from looking at your rep ... no worries. It seems that you do not understand what you are doing. In order to have access on a system, that system needs to provide some sort of **service** that allows you to interact. You can only open a page in a web browser ... if the URL you provide points to a valid target. Same here: you can't just open a SSH connection to some system. Or another approach: assume you enter an **empty** restaurant. No matter how hard you want to - you can't order something if there is no waiter taking orders. Same here.

Comment: That was helpful!! Thanks :)